# Getting Parse Error when installing the .apk file

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am downloading .apk file from the server using DownloadManager after downloading when i am trying to install the app manually it is giving parse error with a message "There is a problem parsing the package".

But same apk when i am downloading through browser and copying to SD card then installing, then it is installing successfully.

So hope there is no issue with the minsdkversion and I already checked on Unknown Sources.

My Code is like this for downloading the apk file

```
        public class UpdateCheckerService extends Service {


    UpdateChecker update_checker;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;
    String Download_path="http://www.xxxxx.com/mobile_api/xxxxxx.apk";

    SharedPreferences preferenceManager;
    String Download_ID = "100";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {
        System.out.println("SERVICE ************ CREATED");

    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent1, int start_id)
    {
        System.out.println("Service started");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
         registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, intentFilter);
         System.out.println("Service started");

        if(isNetworkAvailable())
        {


            if(true)
            {
                System.out.println("Update AVAAILLL:");
                preferenceManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                 downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                 Environment
                  .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                  .mkdirs();

                   Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(Download_path);


                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

                    long download_id = downloadManager.enqueue(request.setTitle("Downloading...")
                            .setDescription("xxxx").setMimeType("application/vnd.android.package-archive").setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                    "xxxxx.apk"));


                    Editor PrefEdit = preferenceManager.edit();
                    PrefEdit.putLong(Download_ID, download_id);
                    PrefEdit.commit();
            }
        }   
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    {

    }



    private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

          @Override
          public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
           query.setFilterById(preferenceManager.getLong(Download_ID, 0));
           Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);

           if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
            int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
            int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
            int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);

            if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){
             //Retrieve the saved download id
             long downloadID = preferenceManager.getLong(Download_ID, 0);

             ParcelFileDescriptor file;

             try {
              file = downloadManager.openDownloadedFile(downloadID);
              Toast.makeText(UpdateCheckerService.this,
                "File Downloaded: " + file.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(UpdateCheckerService.this,
                e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

            }else if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED){
             Toast.makeText(UpdateCheckerService.this,
               "FAILED!\n" + "reason of " + reason,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED){
             Toast.makeText(UpdateCheckerService.this,
               "PAUSED!\n" + "reason of " + reason,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING){
             Toast.makeText(UpdateCheckerService.this,
               "PENDING!",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else if(status == DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING){
             Toast.makeText(UpdateCheckerService.this,
               "RUNNING!",
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
           }
          }

         };

}
```

Here is the logcat

```
11-25 16:31:58.195: D/asset(3422): failed to open Zip archive '/mnt/sdcard/Download/SavariLocal.apk'
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422): Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /mnt/sdcard/Download/SavariLocal.apk
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422): java.io.FileNotFoundException: AndroidManifest.xml
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:486)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:454)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackage(PackageParser.java:402)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageUtil.getPackageInfo(PackageUtil.java:79)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity.onCreate(PackageInstallerActivity.java:242)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageParser(3422):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-25 16:31:58.210: W/PackageInstaller(3422): Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation
```

Please suggest me how to fix this issue, and where i am wrong..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to clean your project.

Comment: I cleaned the project, still same issue..

Comment: Do you get more details from logcat by chance?

Comment: @fasteque I added logcat plz check..

Comment: Just few ideas to check/try: if you have INSTALL_PACKAGES permission set, your apk file name does not have any whitespace and you are 100% sure you are downloading the apk file in a public directory.

Comment: For debugging: i tried like this I download the apk in sd card/Download folder, after that manually i am going to that folder clicking on the apk file then its telling parse error and in logcat it is telling Manifest.xml file is missing.. so i doubt that downloadManager is not downloading the file correctly..

Comment: I hope issue with downloaded file, size of .apk file is 400kb but in SD card its showing 41.04kb.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that after uninstalling the app and than reinstall the apk helped.

There is [another solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_xSthKk0dc) that I did not try but it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue previously. This is how I debugged it. First, install the APK through terminal adb install path_to_your_app/name_of_your_app.apk if you get error message: adb: failed to install name_of_your_app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries this means that the architecture that you are building mismatches with the emulator architecture.

Since this is an APK from external source, you may want to look into repackaging it and build according to your device architecture.You could use this tool: https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Hope this helps